# How to change default comments pattern in Atom (specifically for CSS)

Tags: css, atom-editor

Is there a way to change the default behavior for comments snippet?
Now after press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>/</kbd> I get this:

```css
p {
  color: #000;
  /*margin: 0;*/
}
```

But I want this:

```css
p {
  color: #000;
  /* margin: 0; */
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Open your config file (using `File -> Config`) and add these lines to your config:

```
'.source.css':
  'editor':
    'commentStart': '/\* '
    'commentEnd': ' \*/'
```

This will change the default behavior of comments in CSS files from

```
/*COMMENTED TEXT*/
```

to

```
/* COMMENTED TEXT */
```

Comment: It is does not work.  
You mean 'config.cson' file, right?  
PS. In my case (Mint 18 system) that file sits in `Edit -> Config`

Comment: Yes, the file is `config.cson`. Probably differences between win/linux.

Comment: Probably you not saw first line of my comment above :)  
It not work  
I added your code to config.cson but it still no space within comment

Comment: oh, sorry. I thought you said it **is** working. Which version of atom are you using? and regarding the `config.cson` - are you sure you took the correct file?

Comment: I checked it again and saw that I added your code in `"*":` section. Simply remove the left indent and now the code works. Thanks!